# CSS: hyperlink colour not changing

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the hyperlink color, though for some reason it still remains blue and can't seem to figure out why. The rest work, i.e. size, weight etc but the hyperlink color wouldn't change from blue. Please help.

```
html: <a href="#">Instructions Game</a>

css: a {
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif
    color: #F15B31;
    letter-spacing: 1px
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
```

Comment: You're missing some ';' and a closing '}' in your CSS code

Comment: use semi-colon on end of property
css: a {
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    color: #F15B31;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
}

Comment: And if that still doesn’t work, try putting !important after the color value.

Comment: damn semicolon, now I feel stupid! Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: Always here to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some semicolons `;` and a closing curly brace `}` in your CSS:

```css
a {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  color: #F15B31;
  letter-spacing: 1px font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Instructions Game</a>
```

Comment: Do you think this question need an answer? its just a typo error.

Comment: It's a fairly simple syntax error, and it shows the difference between comma `,` and semicolon `;` in CSS.

Comment: I do not think so. Im not downvoting this but voted to close.